# Простой MYSQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

Есть простой запрос `SELECT country, COUNT(*) as count FROM markers GROUP BY country ORDER BY count DESC`. Тут нас больше всего интересует `country` - он возвращает цифру.

Далее у нас есть другая таблица `countries` с полями `idCountry`, `countryCode` и `countryName`. `idCountry` тут как раз и нужно искать `country` из первого запроса и возвращать `countryCode` и `countryName`.

Задача: нужно первый запрос дописать так, чтобы возвращался массив типа `Array ( [country] => 191 [count] => 583 [countryCode] => RU countryName => Russian Federation )`

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT country, 
    COUNT(*) as count, 
    countries.countryCode, 
    countries.countryName
FROM markers 
LEFT JOIN countries ON markers.country=countries.idCountry
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: Опередил)))))))

Comment: Можно использовать RIGHT JOIN, тогда, при отсутствии в таблице countries значения countryCode строка выбрана не будет.